# How to sendKeys to Text Box which have the same Resource ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, android-resources

I am trying to Automate the login of my app, but they have the same Resource ID. I am using Uiautomatorviewer and do not have any Xpaths in the sign in screen. How do I sendKeys to the second textbox? I am using YAML.

Comment: Instead of ID, use name of that element. For eg. name of the element can be username. So use username instead of ID.

Comment: Got it @GautamBothra thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the solution to my issue. I hope this helps anyone that has two of the same ResourceID on the same page.

```
      - description: Inserts Username
        action: org.getopentest.appium.SendKeys
        args:
          locator: { id: "com.son.sonin.inhouse:id/validation_input_field"}
          text: q20confirmed@mailinator.com 

      - description: Verify that the "Password" text is there
        action: org.getopentest.appium.SendKeys
        args: 
          locator: { xpath: "//android.widget.EditText[@text='PASSWORD']" }
          text: Son2016
```